# Why can't I add PostgreSQL to my path?

Tags: macos, postgresql

After I upgraded to Mavericks, PostgreSQL started playing up, giving this error message whenever I call `pg_restore` without calling the full path:

```
pg_restore: command not found
```

If I specify the full path it works, but that's obvious not optimal:

```
/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U steven -d db/testivate_development $file_path
```

To fix this problem, I have tried removing all versions of PostgreSQL (with Homebrew) and then installed Postgres.app. You can confirm this has worked like this:

```
$ sudo find / -name pg_restore
/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_restore
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

To add PostgreSQL to my path, I've tried adding each of the following lines to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/bashrc` and `~/.zshrc`, restarting after each attempt:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

...as per the postgresapp.com documentation, and then...

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

...as per the comments below.

None of this has solved my problem.

Comment: Is it `Postres.app` or `Postgres93.app`?

Comment: Yes, well spotted -- the app is actually called postgres93.app. I downloaded it from postgresapp.com where the banner promotes postgres.app so I had expected it to take that name, but it doesn't. The documentation on postgressapp.com includes the `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"` which I used.

Comment: I notice two people have flagged this for deletion. It would helpful if someone could please a comment here explaining why as it's a mystery to me. Thanks.

Comment: related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/how-to-run-psql-on-mac-os-x?newreg=aa686de477014c82b8686caaeeb76697

Answer (score 11):

Try adding this line to your .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

and remove or comment out the previous reference.

Comment: If you have a newer version of postgresapp your command will look like  e export  `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 10):

I had this problem too, so instead of adding this to my path in .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

which is what had been recommended, I added

```
export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin:$PATH"
```

instead. The '9.3' is replaced by your own version.

I verified it afterwards using

```
which psql
```

And it found my version, whereas before it reported nothing.

I then then created a test database with

```
createdb test
```

This worked like a charm.

Comment: this is the current situation

Answer (score 7):

If you are using zsh, try this line in your .zshrc and then restart the terminal

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

Answer (score 5):

The examples others are giving that do `export PATH=...` should be the solution to your problem. Since it's not working, you're going to have to debug a problem with your shell that has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.

Firstly, do `which pg_restore` to see if there is another file called `pg_restore` in your path that is confusing things. `which` will usually give no output rather than a helpful error if nothing is found, otherwise it will print the path of what it did found. You may find an old broken install of PostgreSQL in `/usr/local/bin`, for example.

If that didn't work, try `echo $PATH` from a new shell. Do you see the path to the PostgreSQL binary directory in there? If not, `$PATH` is not being set in your shell dot-rc files. This would be the case if you added it to a file called `~/bashrc` since bash(1) actually read `~/.bashrc`. Note the extra dot! I suspect *this* is your actual problem.

If that turns out to not be the problem, you can (re)read the rc file into your current session with `source ~/.bashrc`. Again, `echo $PATH` If it *still* doesn't contain the path, the dot-rc file contains a bug and is not being executed as far as the part that updates `$PATH`. You can do `bash --verbose ~/.bashrc` to run it, and you'll see each command as it's being executed. The failing command should be the last one displayed. (Note that when you run a script with `bash`, it will not set variables in your current shell.)

Comment: Thanks Peter. `which pg_restore` shows just one installation of PostgreSQL -- the one at `/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin`. And `echo $PATH` shows that `/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` is in my path.

Comment: This, is an excellent answer, with lots of steps and multiple solutions. Great stuff, more upvotes needed for you

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the path in your bash_profile

> nano ~/.bash_profile

Add this line (my postgres version is 9.1):

> export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/

Comment: mine is export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Sierra 10.12.1 with PostgreSQL 9.6.0.0

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/Postgres
```

`Postgres` is binary file.

Answer (score 0):

On my macOS, Postgre 9.6 is installed in

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6
```

Answer (score 0):

on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 and PostgreSQL 9.6 it works for me:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin:$PATH
```